Как изменить часовой пояс в контейнере на сайте dockhost
У меня есть контейнер на сайте dockhost.
Я залил туда своего бота с расписанием автобусов. Столкнулся с проблемой, что на сайте стоит время по UTC, мой часовой пояс относительно этого Etc/GMT-7. Бот выдает не правильное время. Как сделать  чтобы время было по моему часовому поясу?

дубликаты, вероятно, где-то здесь
